# magmi with multiple csv and category with references

Tags: magento, csv, import, magmi

I need to automatically update the products from one vendor to magento.
I am using magmi.

This provider makes me 3 .csv: products, categories and images

How I can do to automatically upgrade these products?

In addition I have another problem with the categories .csv, I copy an example:

categories.csv

```
ID_CATEGORY      |   CATEGORY_NAME        | CATEGORY_FATHER_ID
4                |     JARDINERIA         |        0
100              |  Mobiliario jardin     |        4
1085             | Conjuntos de jardin    |       100
102              | Conjuntos de jardin    |       100    
109              | Mobiliario de jardin   |       100
110              |  Polyrattan Marron     |       109
112              |  Polyrattan Marfil     |       109
```

product.csv

```
SKU      | NAME            | CAT  | Shot_description | DESCRIPTION                 | PRICE    | STOCK | img_number
01010080 | BLISTER ALAMBRE | 102  | Alambre          | Carrete alambre galvanizado | 1.230000 | 84    | 1
```

images.csv

```
SKU      | NUM_ORDER | URL
08091264 | 1         | http://www.xxxxx.com/img_artics/08091264.jpg
08091264 | 2         | http://www.xxxxx.com/img_artics/08091264_1.jpg
08091333 | 1         | http://www.xxxxx.com/img_artics/08091333.jpg
08091333 | 2         | http://www.xxxxx.com/img_artics/08091333_1.jpg
08091333 | 3         | http://www.xxxxx.com/img_artics/08091333_2.jpg
```

How I can do it with magmi?

Answer (score 2):

It won't be possible import this file directly.Magmi provides Datapump API. you can use this feature for import this files.

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Magmi_Datapump_API

So here is my approach for import this csv files :

1) Create PHP file for datadump API. 
2) Write PHP script which convert CSV file to array.
3) Import array using data dump API. You can find example on Above link.