# Import categories with magmi datapump

Tags: csv, import, magento-1.9, magmi, datapump

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122916/magmi-with-multiple-csv-and-category-with-references) is an example of my category CSV.

I never used datapump and I can't find any sample code.

I use this code to create a category tree:

```
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');  
        error_reporting(E_ALL);     

        set_time_limit(0);

        $url = "www.xxxxxxxxx.com/category.csv";
        $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
        require_once $mageFilename;
        $app = Mage::app('default');


        $exit= 0;
        $continua = 0;
        $cont = 0;

        $f = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $f);       
        curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        rewind($f);


        function searchForId($id, $array) {
            foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
                if ($val['id'] === $id) {
                    return $val['nombre'];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        while (($data = fgetcsv($f, 10000 , ",")) !== FALSE ) {

                $fila="";   

                foreach($data as $row) {
                    $fila= $fila.$row;                      
                }

                $datos = explode(";",$fila);                    

                // ID_CATEGORY  CATEGORY_NAME   Father_CATEGORY


                $clave = $datos[0];             
                $cat = $datos[1];               
                $padre = $datos[2];                 
                $categoria[$cont]   = array ('id'=>$clave, 'nombre'=>$cat);
                $nomPad = searchForId($padre,$categoria);
}
```

Example Result:

```
[21] => Array
    (
        [id] => 160
        [name] => Madera de Teca
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [id] => 163
        [name] => Polyrattan Natur
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [id] => 165
        [name] => Polyrattan / acero / cristal
    )

[24] => Array
    (
        [id] => 166
        [name] => Polyrattan / forja / cristal
    )
```

How can use this in magmi datapump?

Do I need to import a category creator plugin? How can I combine the sample code with my own.